# remove blanks from strsplit in R

Tags: r

```
> dc1
  V1                V2
1 20140211-0100     |Box
2 20140211-1782     |Office|Ball
3 20140211-1783     |Office
4 20140211-1784     |Office
5 20140221-0756     |Box
6 20140203-0418     |Box
> strsplit(as.character(dc1[,2]),"^\\|")
[[1]]
[1] ""    "Box"


[[2]]
[1] ""             "Office" "Ball"


[[3]]
[1] ""             "Office"


[[4]]
[1] ""             "Office"


[[5]]
[1] ""    "Box"


[[6]]
[1] ""    "Box"
```

How do i remove the blank **("")** from **`strsplit`** results.The result should look like:

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "Box"
> ```

```
[[2]]
[1] "Office"    "Ball"
```

Comment: Your output should not be the one that you show if you use "^\\|", but `[[2]][1] "" "Office|Ball"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check use `lapply` on your list. I changed the definition of your `strsplit` to match your intended output.

```
dc1 <- read.table(text = 'V1                V2
1 20140211-0100     |Box
2 20140211-1782     |Office|Ball
3 20140211-1783     |Office
4 20140211-1784     |Office
5 20140221-0756     |Box
6 20140203-0418     |Box', header = TRUE)

out <- strsplit(as.character(dc1[,2]),"\\|")

> lapply(out, function(x){x[!x ==""]})
[[1]]
[1] "Box"

[[2]]
[1] "Office" "Ball"  

[[3]]
[1] "Office"

[[4]]
[1] "Office"

[[5]]
[1] "Box"

[[6]]
[1] "Box"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(dc1[,2], "[[:alpha:]]+")
[[1]]
 [1] "Box"

[[2]]
 [1] "Office" "Ball"  

[[3]]
 [1] "Office"

[[4]]
 [1] "Office"

[[5]]
 [1] "Box"

[[6]]
 [1] "Box"
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a global solution, but for your example you could try :

`strsplit(sub("^\\|", "", as.character(dc1[,2])),"\\|")`

It removes the first `|` (this is what the regex `"^\\|"` says), which is the reason for the `""`, before performing the split.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can just remove the first element of each vector by calling `"["` in `sapply`

```
> sapply(strsplit(as.character(dc1[,2]), "\\|"), "[", -1)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Box"

# [[2]]
# [1] "Office" "Ball"  

# [[3]]
# [1] "Office"

# [[4]]
# [1] "Office"

# [[5]]
# [1] "Box"

# [[6]]
# [1] "Box"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method uses `nzchar()` after unlisting the result of `strsplit()`:

```
out <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(dc1[,2]),"\\|"))

out[nzchar(x=out)] # removes the extraneous "" marks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library("stringr")

lapply(str_split(dc1$V2, "\\|"), function(x) x[-1])

[[1]]
[1] "Box"

[[2]]
[1] "Office" "Ball"  

[[3]]
[1] "Office"

[[4]]
[1] "Office"

[[5]]
[1] "Box"

[[6]]
[1] "Box"
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is cold but if this helps someone:

```
strsplit(as.character(dc1[,2]),"^\\|") %>% 
               lapply(function(x){paste0(x, collapse="")})
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with **nine votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I’m new to this and may have skipped some conduct details about stackoverflow. By your comment I assume no one should reply in case an answer has a certain amount of votes? 
Yes I should have explained why I suggest differently, will keep that in mind.

Comment: You're always welcome to contribute a new answer, assuming a thread isn't locked. But you should ensure that your answer is truly contributing something new. The more answers a thread has, the more those answers have been validated by the community, the less likely it is that you really have something new to contribute. Regardless, in those cases, it's useful to aid readers by helping them understand _why_ your answer is still relevant. E.g., perhaps there is new syntax or capabilities that you're taking advantage of? Can you [edit] your answer to offer more details?